# Trouble casting shadows in three.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, three.js

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8Lhz0kpc/2/

I've tried to get shadows by following what I've seen in tutorials, but none of the settings seem to work.

My objects are set to cast & receive Shadow

```
@cube.castShadow = true
@cube.receiveShadow = true
```

The floor is set to receiveShadow

```
@floor.castShadow = false
@floor.receiveShadow = true
```

And on the light I have

```
@spotLight.castShadow = true

@spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024
@spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024

@spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 50
@spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 800
@spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 30
@spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5

@spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true
```

Not sure where to go from here, might be something simple I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `sphere.recieveShadow` :)

Comment: just spent an hour on it ^^

Comment: Thats it! Weird how that caused the rest of the objects to not cast / receive shadows too.